# RewriteRule: Bad flag delimiter - Issue after adding to .htaccess

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, delimiter

I've just added this to my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)crm.php(.*)$ /admin/crm.php [QSA, L]

<Limit PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```

And now my apache log is stating this:

```
[Thu Jun 30 15:21:32.676239 2022] [core:alert] [pid 1451:tid 47611971573504] [client 108.162.216.152:45182] /CENSORED/CENSORED/public_html/portal/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: https://webtems.com/
```

Any assistance would be great, thanks :)